# Accessing a site using websocket behind University gateway

Tags: firewall, bypass

I'm trying to access lichess.org from the university network. I can access the site but when I try to join/launch a game, I keep getting reconnecting message. I emailed the admin and he told me they are using websocket.

I try to search the web about this and all I got is that websocket should be able to pass through firewalls.
My questions are:
1. What is blocking websocket then?
2. Can I bypass the gateway (in a legitimate way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1  Perhaps you are using a proxy? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Proxy_traversal) notes that ...

> Some proxy servers are harmless and work fine with WebSocket; others will prevent WebSocket from working correctly, causing the connection to fail. In some cases, additional proxy server configuration may be required, and certain proxy servers may need to be upgraded to support WebSocket.

2  No, all traffic to the Internet has to be routed through a gateway router. If you are using a proxy, consult your admin to find out if it can be bypassed in a legitimate way.

Comment: Thanks. I think you don't know how insignificant Ph.D. students on Universities.